# Angular - POST uploaded file

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, angular2-http

I'm using [Angular](https://angular.io/), [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) to send a file, along with JSON Data to a server.

Below is my code:

```
import {Component, View, NgFor, FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from 'http/http';


@Component({ selector: 'file-upload' })
@View({
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
template: `
<h3>File Upload</h3>

<div>
     Select file:
    <input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)">
</div>

`
})
export class FileUploadCmp {

public file: File;
public url: string;
headers: Headers;


constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('file upload Initialized');
    //set the header as multipart        
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    this.url = 'http://localhost:8080/test';
}

//onChange file listener
changeListener($event): void {
    this.postFile($event.target);
}

//send post file to server 
postFile(inputValue: any): void {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", "Name");
    formData.append("file",  inputValue.files[0]);

    this.http.post(this.url +,
      formData ,
        {
            headers: this.headers

        });
}

}
```

How can I transform the `formData` to String and send it to the server? I remember in [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) (v1) you would use `transformRequest`.

Comment: can't the data be transformed before this.http.post line ? http is an observable and takes options, try to search the source you might find an example, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8ed22ce6e7ce0e00c12b036d02627424c6b4ff35/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts

Comment: Did you had any progress on this?

Comment: There's a pending feature request on GitHub https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2803

Comment: See here, I solved it after a long time fighting 2017.8.25, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879409/2803344

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Look at my code, but be aware. I use async/await, because latest Chrome beta can read any es6 code, which gets by TypeScript with compilation. So, you must replace asyns/await by `.then()`.

Input change handler:

```
/**
 * @param fileInput
 */
public psdTemplateSelectionHandler (fileInput: any){
    let FileList: FileList = fileInput.target.files;

    for (let i = 0, length = FileList.length; i < length; i++) {
        this.psdTemplates.push(FileList.item(i));
    }

    this.progressBarVisibility = true;
}
```

Submit handler:

```
public async psdTemplateUploadHandler (): Promise<any> {
    let result: any;

    if (!this.psdTemplates.length) {
        return;
    }

    this.isSubmitted = true;

    this.fileUploadService.getObserver()
        .subscribe(progress => {
            this.uploadProgress = progress;
        });

    try {
        result = await this.fileUploadService.upload(this.uploadRoute, this.psdTemplates);
    } catch (error) {
        document.write(error)
    }

    if (!result['images']) {
        return;
    }

    this.saveUploadedTemplatesData(result['images']);
    this.redirectService.redirect(this.redirectRoute);
}
```

FileUploadService. That service also stored uploading progress in progress$ property, and in other places, you can subscribe on it and get new value every 500ms.

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {
/**
 * @param Observable<number>
 */
private progress$: Observable<number>;

/**
 * @type {number}
 */
private progress: number = 0;

private progressObserver: any;

constructor () {
    this.progress$ = new Observable(observer => {
        this.progressObserver = observer
    });
}

/**
 * @returns {Observable<number>}
 */
public getObserver (): Observable<number> {
    return this.progress$;
}

/**
 * Upload files through XMLHttpRequest
 *
 * @param url
 * @param files
 * @returns {Promise<T>}
 */
public upload (url: string, files: File[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
            xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        FileUploadService.setUploadUpdateInterval(500);

        xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
            this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

            this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
        };

        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}

/**
 * Set interval for frequency with which Observable inside Promise will share data with subscribers.
 *
 * @param interval
 */
private static setUploadUpdateInterval (interval: number): void {
    setInterval(() => {}, interval);
}
}
```

Comment: I also needed to add: `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');` for it to work

Comment: @patad: do you have problem with it? When I upload xml file, it will automatically add ' ------WebKitFormBoundaryklb8qUzyCQJSI440
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file" ' inside my file. I don't want to add extra data to file during transmission, do you know how to do with that? And for upload image like jpg, after uploaded, it was no longer a jpg file. So my question is: how to keep the original file during transmission?

Comment: Why do we need the `setInterval()` thing?

Answer (score 24):

Looking onto this issue [Github - Request/Upload progress handling via @angular/http](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10424), angular2 http does not support file upload yet.

For very basic file upload I created such service function as a workaround (using [Тимофей's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35519607/1429387)):

```
  uploadFile(file:File):Promise<MyEntity> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let xhr:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(<MyEntity>JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open('POST', this.getServiceUrl(), true);

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file, file.name);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

Comment: Great! For it to work I however needed to add `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');`.

Comment: Thanks! If authorization is required adding this after the xhr.open line worked for me: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + __your_auth_key__);`

Comment: Is this supported now?

Comment: @ManishJain check out the issue status  https://github.com/angular/http/issues/75
So far it is open.

Comment: @AndreyKarayvansky, is there an updated link? I'm getting a 404 page and struggling to find the relevant issue.

Comment: Link updated -- but still no direct support for progress because `fetch` lacks this functionality and Angular does not want to tie the `http` API to XHR...

Comment: I am using a brand new Angular 4 and it seems they didn't fix this already. Either this or I missed the point. The thing is the file never went through. Thanks to your function I got it working. Thank you man.

Comment: still no support from angular - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37597

Answer (score 13):

**your http service file:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Headers, Response, Request, RequestMethod, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Constants } from './constants';
declare var $: any;

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  requestUrl: string;
  responseData: any;
  handleError: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, 
  private http: Http, 
  private constants: Constants, 
  ) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  postWithFile (url: string, postData: any, files: File[]) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', files[0], files[0].name);
    // For multiple files
    // for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //     formData.append(`files[]`, files[i], files[i].name);
    // }

    if(postData !=="" && postData !== undefined && postData !==null){
      for (var property in postData) {
          if (postData.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              formData.append(property, postData[property]);
          }
      }
    }
    var returnReponse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.constants.root_dir + url, formData, {
        headers: headers
      }).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.responseData = res.json();
            resolve(this.responseData);
          },
          error => {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            reject(error);
          }
      );
    });
    return returnReponse;
  }
}
```

**call your function (Component file):**

```
onChange(event) {
    let file = event.srcElement.files;
    let postData = {field1:"field1", field2:"field2"}; // Put your form data variable. This is only example.
    this._service.postWithFile(this.baseUrl + "add-update",postData,file).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

**your html code:**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="documents" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="stock.documents" #documents="ngModel">
```

Comment: One of the only answers that actually uses angular

Comment: How can I fix this `error TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'Element'.` thanks

Comment: `onChange() {...}` should be `onChange(event) {...}` will fix the error: property files does not exist ;)

Comment: does not work for me. it is unable to find the file on backend node which uses multer.

Answer (score 4):

In my project , I use the XMLHttpRequest to send multipart/form-data.
I think it will fit you to.

and the [uploader](https://github.com/wangzilong/angular2-multipartForm/blob/master/app/plugins/multipart-upload/multipart-uploader.ts)  code

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.example.com/rest/api', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(formData);
```

Here is example : https://github.com/wangzilong/angular2-multipartForm

Comment: Just linking to your own library (or utility) is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using it to do so and disclaiming makes for a better answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to create your own inline TS-Class, since the FormData Class is not well supported at the moment:

```
var data : {
  name: string;
  file: File;
} = {
  name: "Name",
  file: inputValue.files[0]
  };
```

Then you send it to the Server with JSON.stringify(data)

```
let opts: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
opts.method = RequestMethods.Post;
opts.headers = headers;
this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(data),opts);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility
Support isn't actually so bad.  I would imagine JSON.stringify would have some issues if the uploaded files happen to be binaries or some such thing..