# Angular 2 File Upload?

Tags: angular, file-upload

I am trying to do file upload in Angular 2. Trying

```
let file:FileList = inputEl.files[0];
console.log(file);
    this.http.post(url, file)
         .map(res => {
              return  res.headers.get("content-type");
            })
            .catch(err => {
             return Observable.throw(err);
            })
            .subscribe((res) => { // <-- this function
                console.log(res)
            });
```

I can see the POST call happening now. But I still am not able to see the file
upload happening, How exactly the File Upload request should look like.

Comment: Have you actually `.subscribe`d to the POST?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually new to angular 2. Was able to do simple form submit but not able to wrap my mind around how to do a file upload, also not sure of the structure in my java code for file upload

Comment: ...that doesn't answer my question. Could you give a [mcve]? What comes *after* `.post(...)`?

Comment: I havent added aything after that.

Comment: Well that might be the problem; you have to subscribe to observables to make them do anything. I'd suggest looking at the tutorials for Angular 2 http.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added .map to the http post call, updated the sample above still no success.

Comment: Observables are lazy and are only executed when callbacks are subscribed to them.

Comment: Why would Chrome not show the call happening at all, I see Other codes working with the same syntax?

Comment: @sushilbharwani presumably what you're seeing is `return`ed and then `subscribe`d to elsewhere in the codebase, or resolved with `| async` in the markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**your http service file:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Headers, Response, Request, RequestMethod, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Constants } from './constants';
declare var $: any;

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  requestUrl: string;
  responseData: any;
  handleError: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, 
  private http: Http, 
  private constants: Constants, 
  ) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  postWithFile (url: string, postData: any, files: File[]) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', files[0], files[0].name);
    // For multiple files
    // for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //     formData.append(`files[]`, files[i], files[i].name);
    // }

    if(postData !=="" && postData !== undefined && postData !==null){
      for (var property in postData) {
          if (postData.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              formData.append(property, postData[property]);
          }
      }
    }
    var returnReponse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.constants.root_dir + url, formData, {
        headers: headers
      }).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.responseData = res.json();
            resolve(this.responseData);
          },
          error => {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            reject(error);
          }
      );
    });
    return returnReponse;
  }
}
```

**call your function (Component file):**

```
onChange(event) {
    let file = event.srcElement.files;
    let postData = {field1:"field1", field2:"field2"}; // Put your form data variable. This is only example.
    this._service.postWithFile(this.baseUrl + "add-update",postData,file).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

**your html code:**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="documents" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="stock.documents" #documents="ngModel">
```

**your server file (Like PHP):**

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Http requests are only sent when you subscribe to them.

```
this._http.post("url", "file")
         .map(res => {
              return  res.headers.get("content-type");
            })
            .catch(err => {
             return Observable.throw(err);
            })
            .subscribe((res) => { // <-- this function
                console.log(res)
            })
```

You can find more about creating http client with Angular 2 [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html).

Comment: thanks i can see the POST call happening now, But i still am not able to see the file Upload happening can you help me with figuring how exactly should my POST call look like, I want to upload a file along with some of its MetaData.

Comment: I haven't done a file upload by myself yet, so i don't have a clear idea about how it should look. This looks like a full example. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423348/angular2-post-uploaded-file

Answer (score 0):

```
1. remember when you are submitting form data with file , header should be blanked 


        let headers = new Headers();  

        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  

2. Rest You can follow from upper example @Bharat Chauhan

3. i tested with all others headers , but it worked if its leave blanked ! 


Step 1.   <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />  

Step 2. 
 fileChangeEvent(e:any):void{





 let commentOperation:Observable<any>;

 let fileList: FileList = e.target.files;
 let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);

 commentOperation = this.test1Service_.submitComment( formData);
  commentOperation.subscribe(
                                fileUpload => {

                                  console.log(fileUpload)
                                }, 
                                err => {
                                    // Log errors if any
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                                );



 }

Step 3: 

  submitComment (body: any): Observable<any> {



        let headers = new Headers();



        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  

        return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl,body , options) // ...using post request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }


Step 4: PHP : 



header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');





if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
  exit;
}

$path = 'uploads/';

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
  $originalName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $ext = '.'.pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $generatedName = md5($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']).$ext;
  $filePath = $path.$generatedName;

  if (!is_writable($path)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status' => false,
      'msg'    => 'Destination directory not writable.'
    ));
    exit;
  }

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status'        => true,
      'originalName'  => $originalName,
      'generatedName' => $generatedName
    ));
  }
}
else {
  echo json_encode(
    array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No file uploaded.')
  );
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fileChange(event) {

```
let fileList: FileList = event.srcElement.files;
if(fileList.length > 0) {
    let file: File = fileList[0];
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post(`${this.apiEndPoint}`, formData, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log('success'),
            error => console.log(error)
        )
}
```

}

I took reference from : [File Upload In Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular-2)
But got it working after changing 'Content-Type' to 'enctype' and 'event.target.files' to 'event.srcElement.files'