# How can I make HTTP POST in Ionic 2

Tags: html, http, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm making an APP of my homepage. And I got a problem in making a 'Writing page'. 
I have to POST some data and image. And I can't get how to POST image!

I searched and found this code. but it's still not working... I think the `FormData` is Empty. Can you tell me why the `FormData` is empty or  Can  you show me a better way to POST **Image and Texts** in `Ionic 2`?

This is my HTML code..

```
<input type="file" (change)="write($event)"/>
```

and my TypeScript code

```
write(event) {

  let file = event.srcElement.files.item(0);

  let formData: FormData = new FormData();

  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  });

  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });

  formData.append('bf_file', file, file.name);
  formData.append('wr_subject', 'Just Testing');
  formData.append('wr_content', 'Some content...');
  formData.append('bo_table', 'table');

  this.http.post('http://www.myhomepage.com/write_update.php', formData, options).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.text());
  });

}
```

Please help me...

Comment: This [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40216616) says you need to retrieve the file from `event.target.files[0]`. Also, are you sure the problem is not with `write_update.php`? Try sending the request to a debugging service like `https://httpbin.org/post` and see what it returns.

Comment: @AngularFrance Thanks, I will try it...