# Get errror "Unsupported ContentType: application/vnd.ms-excel" when upload file in angular

Tags: angular

I tried to upload CSV file in angular 5 using the method stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442595/6105852

but got the errror "Unsupported ContentType: application/vnd.ms-excel". I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the backend, not with angular...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by wrapping the csv file in a Blob object as follow:

`formData.append('file', new Blob([file], {type: 'text/csv'}), file.name);`

And it worked.