# How to upload image and save using Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, image-uploading

i have a image upload section where i need to upload an image. But when i save i get an error saying `generic`. can anyone help me to solve this.

**HTML:**

```
<label >Image</label>
<div >
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" (change)="readUrlAdd($event)" style="display:none;"/> <label for="file" >Add Image</label>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
readUrlAdd(event: any) {
    var files = event.srcElement.files;
    var filename = new Date().getTime() + '.' + files[0].name.split(".")[1];
    var imgFile = new File([files[0]], filename, { type: files[0].type });
    var file_data = imgFile;
    this.ApiService
      .uploadImage(file_data)
      .subscribe(
        image => {
          console.log(image);
          var fileName = image.result.files.file[0].providerResponse.location;
          console.log(fileName);
          this.tutorials = fileName;
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
  }
```

API:

```
uploadImage (files) {
  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', files);
  return this.http.post(urlBase + '/tutorials/tutorial?token=' + token,fd)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload In Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [file uploader](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) for uploading file. for installation  use following command. found [demo](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/master/demo/components/file-upload/simple-demo.html)

```
npm i ng2-file-upload --save
```

Comment: added link of demo also

Answer (score 0):

event.srcElement will not work in all browsers, please try the below

```
const files = event.target.files || event.srcElement.files;
const imgFile = files[0];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `headers` with `request`

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('token', token); // Try to pass token in header
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  

return this.http.post(urlBase + '/tutorials/tutorial,fd, options)
              .map((res: Response) => res.json() || {})
              .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: if i use options i get an error saying user not found

Comment: I think it's `token`'s issue make sure you are passing correct token, or At server side expecting token from query param `?token=`, try to pass token in header like `headers.append('token', token);`

Comment: my functions itself is not working, is the code written by me is correct?

Comment: Your code looks correct but try to `debug` your code and check what exactly error is. One more think pass selected file as it is to server and rename your file from back-end.