# How to upload a file with httpclient in angular/ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to upload a file with the angular/ionic framework. I've been able to piece together some rough outline on how to do it, but I'm stuck with how to get "file" from the file-input.

What I have in my view is a ViewChild matching the input element:

```
@ViewChild('file', { read: ElementRef }) myfile: ElementRef;
public files: Set<File> = new Set<File>();
```

A callback function that is called everytime the files changes:

```
  onFilesAdded() {
    alert(this.myfile.nativeElement.outerHTML);  
    const files: { [key: string]: File } = this.myfile.nativeElement.files;
    for (let key in files) {
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
        this.files.add(files[key]);
        alert(key);
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem with the above code is '.files'. I have tried a couple of different approaches from different sources, but there's always some element that is undefined. How can i actually access the 'files' property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload In Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@ViewChild`, pass in the element from the change event.

In the HTML:

```
 <input type="file" (change)="onFilesAdded($event.target.files)">
```

and in the TypeScript:

```
 onFilesAdded(files) {
    for (let key in files) {
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
        this.files.add(files[key]);
        alert(key);
      }
    }
  }
```