# Http post a file data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, http, input

I have two `<input>` tag on my client to choose a file. Once the client choose the files (24-bit BMP 640*480), I have to make a http.post so that I could save the imageData of each file and make a http.get when I need it. I tried posting an ImageData object or just an Uint8ClampedArray but I was getting some errors. Now I tried to convert it to base64 and send it but I'm still not getting anything.

This is my http.post:

```
public submitInfo(): void {
  this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/sologame", { "name": this.game.gameName, "image1": this.game.picture }, HTTP_OPTIONS).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError("submitInfo"))).subscribe();
}
```

This is the error I'm getting now that I'm trying to send a base64 string:[image]

How can I send the data of my image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload In Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do it:

1. Send binary data

---

```
onUpload(selectedFile: File) {
    this.http.post('api/file-upload', selectedFile).subscribe(...);
}
```

2. Send as FormData

---

```
onUpload(selectedFile: File) {
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('file', selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post('api/file-upload', uploadData).subscribe(...);
}
```