# File converting into empty array on angular to laravel post request

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to perform a basic Laravel 5 `post` request which simply do the following:

- Save some data into a database
- Stores a `file` (image) into public storage under a name which is a possible combo of 20 random numbers following '.jpg'
- Save a url (which is used to locate the image in an `img` tag. I'm aware this isn't the best approach so feel free to post)

However, when performing an ordinary `post` request with no special headers from `angular 6` to `laravel 5`, for some reason the `File` keeps converting into an `empty` array. (Before and after shots are below)

Before:

```
0: Object { id: 0, body: null, file: File }
```

After:

```
0: Object { id: 0, body: null, file: [] }
```

The `File` is full and is used to create a preview on a canvas before submitting so It works. The console is logging this data the line before posting and returning the `$req Request` before performing any php code in Laravel.

So the only place anything could get lost in translation is the in between. Code is as follows:

Angular 6:

```
postToLaravel(object) {
  console.log(object.message);
  this.http.post(this.url + '/add/message', object).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Laravel 5:

```
function addMessage(Request $req) {
    return $req->messages;
```

The `empty` array keeps pushing nothing to `storage` under a name its registered as a `jpg` file but no image is shown.

On the component that images are uploaded we have the following block take place after a (change)="" event:

```
onFileSelected(e: any) {
    this.sectedFile = e.target.files[0];
    this.isImage = true;
    this.messageService.addImage(this.id, this.sectedFile);
    this.preview();
  }
```

The service function just finds the right object and adds a file:

```
addImage(id, file) {
    var index = this.data.findIndex(x => x['id'] == id);
    this.data[index]['body'] = null;
    this.data[index]['file'] = file;
  }
```

And when the submit button is pressed it just takes all the variables in the service and compacts them into an object. this object contains `messages` which is an array of further objects (the objects are as shown at the top) (If that made sense)

```
pushMessageToServer() {
  this.messageService.postToLaravel({
    title: this.title,
    location: this.location,
    gender: this.gender,
    age: this.age,
    deadline: this.deadline,
    messages: this.data
  });
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Let me know should You need any extra info.

Comment: How does your javascript part look like, that needs to be fixed first

Comment: can you update your answer with that code, so that it's more readable

Comment: Ok I am not familiar with Angular, but the code you pasted above does not have a submit function where exactly do you post (xhr) the data to the server (Laravel)

Comment: I have provided the submit block you asked for at the end. It basically just compiles all the local variables into an object and posts that in a http post request to Laravel

Comment: ok can you console.log the posted data in your javascript promise and also `dd($req->all())` in your controller method and see if you get the correct data?

Comment: You need to set the encoding type to `multipart/form-data`. Are you using a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)?

Comment: @MarcoFlorian I was not using FormData no. After some research should I convert all my data into a single FormData and post it with the content-type header as "multipart/form-data"? Or should I just put all my images into a new FD each and post that in place of the File in each object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular

Comment: @MarcoFlorian Even setting the headers and attempting to send very basic form data is still throwing the same issue when it reaches the api. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/file-upload-always-comes-up-as-empty-when-accessed-in-controller-1?page=1

Comment: try $req->get('messages'); or $req->input('messages');

Comment: Another way to check for data in laravel is `has()` method. `if($req->has('messages')){`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out images in FormData are passed through and displayed as empty objects in the console. I just needed to know how to grab them. Thanks for your help everyone