# How to post multipart/form-data from angular to Django REST API

Tags: django, angular, angular6, angular-forms

I'm using **Django REST API** and **Angular 6** for the frontend.

I have defined an ImageField in the **Profile** model which accepts File input.

In angular application, I'm generating **File** object from the Base64 image data and sending to the endpoint with header as **Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data'**

The data sent is

[image]

where `first_name` and `profile.avatar` are the form fields and `profile.avatar` contains the image file.

But in the network tab the parameters sent for `profile.avatar` is empty dictionary.

[image]

**How can I send media file as form-data from Angular to REST API?**

> Edit 2: Code

```
submit() {

    // call method that creates a blob from dataUri
    // imgSrc[0] contains base64 string
    const imageBlob = this.dataURItoBlob(this.imgSrc[0]);

    const extension = imageBlob['type'].split('/')[1];
    const imageName = 'file123' + '.' + extension;

    const imageFile = new File([imageBlob], imageName, { type: imageBlob['type'] });

    const fb = new FormData();
    fb.append('profile.avatar', imageFile, imageFile.name);

    this.account.updateProfile(fb, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
    );
  }


  dataURItoBlob(dataURI: string) {
    // Split from , (comma)
    const b64Split = dataURI.split(',');

    const extension = 'png';

    // remove data:image/png;base64, from the base64 string
    dataURI = dataURI.replace(b64Split[0] + ',', '');

    const byteString = atob(dataURI);
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      int8Array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'image/png' });

    return blob;
  }
```

The `updateProfile` method is sending data using `PATCH` method.

Comment: Please share the relevant code i.e. how you are generating File object from the Base64 image data and sending to server.

Comment: These links helped me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y     https://academind.com/learn/angular/snippets/angular-image-upload-made-easy/

Comment: @mehamasum check Edit 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload In Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same issue. In my request header, I had specified a content-type. Once I removed that, I was able to send both text fields and a file. For your post request, you must also be using formData like so:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('textOrFileField', yourTextOrFile);
```

Hope this helps!