# Uploading an object containing image to Mongodb using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I want to upload an object containing image in it to the mongodb database using nodejs but i am no able to do so.

**Angular File**

```
onSelectedFile(event){
this.edit_image = event.target.files[0];   
}


editProfile(e){ 
const user={
  email:this.edit_email,
  img:this.edit_image,
}
console.log("To Update");
console.log(user);
this._authService.editProfile(user)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.dataFromService=data;
        this.user=this.dataFromService.user;
        console.log(data);
      })
}
```

**In Service File**

```
editProfile(user){
let headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers=headers.append('content-type','application/json');
console.log("Updating Profile");
console.log(user);
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/profile/edit_Profile',user,{headers:headers})
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
  }
```

**In Nodejs File**

```
router.post('/edit_profile', (req, res) => {
let updateProfile = {
    email: req.body.email,
    img: req.body.img
};

console.log("Profile");
console.log(updateProfile); //to check the data
console.log("Profile");

Profile.updateP(updateProfile, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
        console.log("Update User");
        console.log(user);
        res.json({
            user: user
        })
    }
})
})
```

**While logging the data in profileUpdate it is printing the empty value of the img**

**User Schema**

```
const profileSchema = schema({
email: {
    type: String,
},
img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
});
```

I want to update an existing profile but i am not able to use multer or even pass the image data from the angular file to the nodejs file

Comment: You won't be able to send "image data" within a JSON body without actually encoding it first. What you probably really mean to do is use is actually `multipart/form-data` ( which is actually what "multer" gets it's name from ) to send with the request instead. Multer can accept that as binary content which also aligns with the `Buffer` type in the mongoose schema, and stored as BSON `Binary` actually in MongoDB. And there's a Mime Type with multipart boundaries as well, which also can be extracted from multer and stored within the respective field of the data.

Comment: See also [File Upload In Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40214772/2313887) and the [Multer README](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) which is really quite descriptive. Note the exposed [File Information](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) from multer actually has a `buffer` property which exposes a `Buffer` for the full binary content of the file/image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your image into base64 format which is very easy to handle and store in database
function for converting image to base64:-

```
var fs = require('fs');

function base64_encode(){
    var imageAsBase64 = fs.readFileSync('test.png', 'base64');
    // code to store it in the mongodb here
}
```

function for converting base64 to image:-

```
    var fs = require('fs');

    function base64_decode(){
        var imageAsBase64 //some base64 encoded string
        var data = imageAsBase64..replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "")
        fs.writeFile("out.png", data, 'base64', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
         });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than uploading an image to the database use something like s3 to store the image and upload the link to that image on mongodb

Comment: But how can I use multer ?

Comment: setup multer as a middleware . See multer documentation.Store the image in local file system then use a image storage service upload the image then store the link in mongodb