# how to submit image and text field in single API endpoint using drf and angular

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

Good day guy i'm working on an drf api endpoint that requires user uploading image and text to the same endpoint, i've done all that is required but i still keep getting error, below is snippet of my code and error msg

APIVIEW

```
class CreateProfileView(APIView):
  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
  serializer_class = schoolProfileSerializer
  queryset = schoolProfile.objects.all()
  permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

  def post(self, request):

    file_upload = schoolProfileSerializer(data =request.data, instance=request.user)
    if file_upload.is_valid():
      file_upload.save()
      return Response(file_upload.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(file_upload.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST )
```

SERIALIZER

```
class Base64Imagefield(serializers.ImageField):

  def to_internal_value(self, data):
    if isinstance(self, six.string_types):
      if 'data: ' in data and ';base64, ' in data:
        header, data = data.split(';base64,')
      try:
        decode_file = base64.b64decode(data)
      except TypeError:
        self.fail('invalide image')

      file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:16]
      file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decode_file)
      complete_file_name = "%s.%s" %(file_name, file_extension)
      data = ContentFile(decode_file, name=complete_file_name)

    return super(Base64Imagefield, self).to_internal_value(data)  

  def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decode_file):
    extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decode_file)
    extension = 'jpg' if extension == 'jpeg' else extension
    return extension

class schoolProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )
  id = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk', read_only=True)
  email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email', read_only=True)
  username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', read_only=True)
  badge = Base64Imagefield(max_length=None, use_url=True)

  class Meta:
    model = schoolProfile
    fields = ( 'email', 'id', 'username', 'school_name',
          'address', 'badge', 'gender', 'level',
        )

  def create(self, validated_data, instance=None):
    if 'user' in validated_data:
      user = validated_data.pop('user')
    else:
      user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
    profile, created_profile = schoolProfile.objects.update_or_create(user=user,   
      **validated_data)
    return profile
```

Angular service

```
postSchoolProfile(profile: schoolProfile):Observable<schoolProfile>{
  const url= `${environment.mainUrl}/school-profile/create`
  return this.httpClient.post<schoolProfile>(url, {profile})
}
```

Error msg

```
detail  "Unsupported media type \"application/json\" in request.
```

can anyone help out pls ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File Upload In Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular). You are sending a request with the wrong `Content-Type` header, "application/json" instead of "multipart/form-data"

Comment: it didn't i've tried used that earlier, it didnt work and also having issue appending multiple form fields to formdata