# Test angular http service with jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I would like to test if one of my helper functions are being called in the http service layer but I get a failed test. I am new to jest so please tell me know what am I doing wrong

Service Layer

```
public customerUpload(
    file: Blob,
    name?: string): Observable<CustomerResponse> {
    
    if (name!== '') {
      parameters = addQueryPara(name, 'name');
    }

return this.http.post(file, parameters)
)
```

I want to check if I called CustomerUpload with name, it should call addQueryPara

My Spec file Test

```
import * as helper from 'app/shared/helper.ts';


describe('customerService', () => {
  let service: customerService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(customerService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });


describe('when customer is called', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const response = getMockResponse();
    jest.spyOn(service, 'customerUpload').mockReturnValue(of(response) as any);
  });

  it('should add http params', () => {
    service.customerUpload(new Blob(), 'learn');
    expect(jest.spyOn(helper, 'addQueryPara')).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // This is failing
  });
});

});
```

addQueryPara is failing. How can I make sure if I pass a parameter, it calls addQueryPara?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should import the Service you are going to test, so you can inject it later. In this case, as you need to mock the `HttpClient` so it doesn't make any real request, you can do it with `TestBed` and `HttpClientTestingModule` ([here is the official Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#angular-testbed) for jasmine, but it is similar).

```js
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service.ts'; // change this to the name of your route

describe('CustomerService', () => {
  let service: CustomerService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [CustomerService] // <- Here we import the real service
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(CustomerService);
  });
```

Then, in your test I see you try to mock the HTTP POST request. For that you can use `HttpTestingController`, that is part of `HttpClientTestingModule` ([here you have a good tutorial](https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/testing/services/http/using-httptestingmodule#complete-spec-example) on HTTP testing with Angular).

```js
describe("when customerUpload is called", () => {
  const mockFile = // your mock
  afterEach(() => {
    // After every test, assert that there are no more pending requests.
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });
  it("should invoke HTTP POST with the file", () => {
    service.customerUpload(mockFile);

    // Check for correct requests: should have made one request to POST search from expected URL
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(customerUrl); // the url you expect to be called, including the queryParams, e.g.: customerUrl:4200?name=Mario
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("POST");

    // Provide each http request with a mock response
    req.flush(getMockResponse()); 
  });
});
```

This is unit test theory: if the `addQueryPara` function is not exported outside of this service, you should not test it explicitly. Simply test that the result `customerUpload` works as you expect when `name !== ''`

Also, I'm not sure about that implementation for uploading a file, you should check out [this comment about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40216616/1974681).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `jest` but I am thinking when you do `jest.spyOn(...).mockReturnValue(...)` you are stubbing the method and losing the implementation details with `mockReturnValue`.

Another thing is, you are spying AFTER calling the method but you should be spying before.

I would first use `HttpClientTestingModule` instead of the real `HttpClientModule` for testing so actual API calls are not sent and you can assert which API calls were sent.

Try removing the `mockReturnValue` and seeing if it passes.

```
import * as helper from 'app/shared/helper.ts';


describe('customerService', () => {
  let service: customerService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // !! Change to HttpClientTestingModule
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(customerService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });


describe('when customer is called', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const response = getMockResponse();
    !! remove mockReturnValue
    jest.spyOn(service, 'customerUpload');
  });

  it('should add http params', () => {
    // !! move this up before calling the method so we are actually spying before
    const addSpy = jest.spyOn(helper, 'addQueryPara');
    service.customerUpload(new Blob(), 'learn');
    // !! assert now
    expect(addSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});

});
```

Check this link out for testing services with HTTP: https://testing-angular.com/testing-services/#testing-a-service-that-sends-http-requests

It uses Karma and Jasmine instead of Jest but the idea is the same.

Comment: it still fails and says expected value 1 but actual 0

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.

Comment: Hello, did you try jasmine-auto-spies ? Works very well to mock HttpClient calls. Here you can find examples : https://danielk.tech/home/how-to-test-angular-http-services. Here are the actual project with a Jest version : https://github.com/hirezio/auto-spies. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the following line:

```
jest.spyOn(service, 'customerUpload').mockReturnValue(of(response) as any);
```

As [AliF50 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72575039/8838570), by doing this you are completely mocking the inner behavior of `service.customerUpload` therefore the actual implementation will never be called and it will always return `of(response)`.

Additionally you might want to change your import for the `HttpClientModule` to `HttpClientTestingModule` in order to enable you mock and spy easily whenever you make any http request such as `this.http.post`;

This is how your code could look like (I assume `addQueryPara` is a typo but didn't change it for consistency with your sample):

```
import * as helper from 'app/shared/helper.ts';
import { customerService } from './customer-service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';


describe('customerService', () => {
    let service: customerService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(customerService);
        httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('when customer is called', () => {
        it('should add http params', () => {
            // Given.
            const mockFile = new Blob();
            const mockName = 'learn';

            const addQueryParaSpy = jest.spyOn(helper, 'addQueryPara');

            // When.
            service.customerUpload(mockFile, mockName);

            // Then.
            expect(addQueryParaSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockName, 'name');
        });
    });
});
```