# Test service and observable using jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am switching from jasmine to jest for angular unit test. I updated the spec code for testing the service to the following:

```
....
describe( 'My Test', () => { 
   let myService: any;
   ...
   
   beforeEach(() => {
      myService = {
         theMethodInTheService: jest.fn()
      }
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         ....
      })
      myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
   })
   it('should fetch data from user endpoint', () => {
       myService.theMethodInTheService.subscribe( ( res:any ) => {
            expect(res).toBe('theExpectedResponse');
       });
       const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(theExpectedUrl);
       expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
       req.flush('theExpectedResponse);
   });
})
```

But the fails with the following error:

> TypeError: myService.theMethodInTheService.subscribe is not a function

`theMethodInTheService` returns an observable. How can I run a test for this case using jest. In [jest doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions), I cannot see an exact description and/or specific method or use case.

Comment: What are you actually trying to test here? You're appear to be replacing the service with a test double _and_ using the HTTP testing module, which leaves no actual implementation involved at all. Also is `myService.theMethodInTheService.subscribe(...)` really the right API expectation - normally you'd _invoke_ a method, for one thing.

Comment: And what are you trying to say here? Is this your way to explain and clarify the use case? No need for such/your advise! Also I didn't paste the complet code so, that you can provide a final input!!

Comment: Requesting clarification from the author of a post is one of the documented purposes of [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). What you've posted seems internally inconsistent, so I'm asking for more information - it might be clear to you, but for useful SO content it has to be clear to _other people_ too. You haven't given a [mre], as suggested in [ask], or even shown what (presumably passing, although I'll concede that doesn't mean you involved the actual implementation before migration either) test you're migrating _from_.

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking your service here

```
myService = {
         theMethodInTheService: jest.fn()
      }
```

like an object with "empty" function. And in this way the real code will not be executed, only this mock. So it's not needed.

Also, you are not calling it, if theMethodInTheService is not a getter you should make a call to it.

```
 myService.theMethodInTheService().subscribe( ( res:any ) => {
            expect(res).toBe('theExpectedResponse');
       });
```

but be sure to provide it properly in configureTestingModule

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], 
      providers: [MyService/* , ... and other services (or mocks for them) MyService depends on*/] 
    });

    myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });
```

Also, consider looking here : [Test angular http service with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72566904/test-angular-http-service-with-jest)

**UPDATE:**
example:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeBackendCallService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
  public theMethodInTheService(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get('/some-api');
  }
}

describe('SomeBackendCallService', () => {
  let service: SomeBackendCallService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [SomeBackendCallService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(SomeBackendCallService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should fetch data from user endpoint', () => {
    const mockResponse = 'some result';
    service.theMethodInTheService().subscribe((response) => {
      expect(response).toEqual(mockResponse);
    });
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('/some-api');
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    req.flush(mockResponse);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have been trying all the suggestions you mentioned. Also other options. Test keep failing. I get no errors regarding `subscribe`, but  I face other one, when following your proposal is: `Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: /dailies/svc/v2/users/xxxxx", found none.`. I am quite sure that the method call with subscription isn't triggered in this case, that's why the assertion `httpTestingController.expectOne(theExpectedUrl);` is failing.

Comment: you can check if your theMethodInTheService simply by placing a breakpoint in your IDE, and debugging your test.