# Uploading a file in a form group in angular and send it to Django API

Tags: django, angular, file, django-rest-framework

I have a form in the front-end having multiple entries, i.e name, email, phone and also a file field entry. A Form group is used to group all these elements in the same form in Angular. There is also a corresponding model in Django, (Using Django Rest Framework).
I could not manage to have the file sent to the API, even if the rest of the data is sent correctly and saved on the back-end.

First, I am able to upload the file successfully to Front-end, below I log in the console:
[image]

Second, the object I send is something like this:

```
{"name":"name", "age":49, "email":"email@field.com", "file":File}
```

The File in the JSON is the same file object displayed in the console above.

I tested my backend with Postman, I was able to succesfully have the file as well as the other data saved. (I believe the problem to be more on the Front-end side ).

Solutions I found for uploading file in Angular used form data (i.e [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular)), these solutions were not convenient as the form consists only of a file, however in my case I have file as well as other data (Form Group).

Another thing I tried that did not work was the following: putting a form Data object with the file in the "file" key of the JSON to be sent. Still, this it did not work.

Also, this is how I upload the file in angular:

```js
   public file: File | null = null;
   public form: FormGroup;
   formData = new FormData();
   
   ngOnInit(){
     this.form = this.fb.group({
            name: [], [Validators.required]],
            age: [],
            email: [], [Validators.required]],
            file: []});
    
    fileUploadedHandler(file) {
        this.file = file;
        this.formData.append("file",file, file.name);
        this.form.patchValue({file:file}); //this.formData});
        this.createDocumentForm.updateValueAndValidity();
        console.log(file);}
  }
```

Any propositions to solve this ?

Comment: Well I have faced the same issue. Formdara and DRF works in a specific way. Could you please show me what is the payload in frontend and what is the 'request.data' object in views? I might have a solution for you

Comment: I was able to solve it finally, I'll post the answer soon.
Before solving the problem, request.data had the same data as in the form, only the file field was empty.

Comment: Yes, it shows empty but the data is still there in the case of formdata.
If you face any issue serializing the problem, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem. First I had to use formData instead of formGroup, It was also possible to have multiple fields in formData using append method :

```
this.formData.append("file",file, file.name);
this.formData.append("name",name);
this.formData.append("age",age);
```

I had also to revisit the HTTP headers used to submit the form to the API, this was the blocking part.
In my case I had to **Remove** the 'Content-Type': 'application/json' from the headers. The new working one was:

```
working_headers = new HttpHeaders({
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Authorization": 'Token laksjd8654a6s56a498as5d4a6s8d7a6s5d4a',
  });
```