# angular 5 spring boot 1.5.8 multiple files and multiple properties into one object,using POST ,Request rest api spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, angular5

I'm using angular5 and Spring boot. How can I send multiple file and some other properties into one object, i  have a class Student, now i have properties like, first name, last name, email, profile image file, id card image file, father id card image file into one object student,how i pass one object that have all things (all properties and some files like idCard image , profile iamge) to springBoot rest api for POST Request.

Answer (score 0):

**http service file:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Headers, Response, Request, RequestMethod, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Constants } from './constants';
declare var $: any;

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  requestUrl: string;
  responseData: any;
  handleError: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, 
  private http: Http, 
  private constants: Constants, 
  ) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  postWithFile (url: string, postData: any, files: File[]) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', files[0], files[0].name);
    // For multiple files
    // for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //     formData.append(`files[]`, files[i], files[i].name);
    // }

    if(postData !=="" && postData !== undefined && postData !==null){
      for (var property in postData) {
          if (postData.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              formData.append(property, postData[property]);
          }
      }
    }
    var returnReponse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.constants.root_dir + url, formData, {
        headers: headers
      }).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.responseData = res.json();
            resolve(this.responseData);
          },
          error => {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            reject(error);
          }
      );
    });
    return returnReponse;
  }
}
```

**call your function (Component file):**

```
onChange(event) {
    let file = event.srcElement.files;
    let postData = {field1:"field1", field2:"field2"}; // Put your form data variable. This is only example.
    this._service.postWithFile(this.baseUrl + "add-update",postData,file).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

**your html code:**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="documents" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="stock.documents" #documents="ngModel">
```

Note : This code is working code for me you just need to modify this based on your parameters.

Refer this : [Angular - POST uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423348/angular-post-uploaded-file)

Comment: It would be good to see the corresponding Spring Controller method